# scraping list of values from drop-down

Tags: python, selenium, dropdown

I am trying to scrape the list of companies from a dropdown in the website https://www.goodjobsfirst.org/violation-tracker , the drop-down is the parent company one.

I am running the following code

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser =  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
url = ('https://www.goodjobsfirst.org/violation-tracker')
browser.get(url)
browser.maximize_window()  
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(Select(browser.find_element_by_id("edit-field-violation-parent-value")))

browser.quit()
```

but for I get the error

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="edit-field-violation-parent-value"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

I checked different times and edit-field-violation.. is indeed the ID. I also tried to get it using the Xpath and other selectors but without luck. What am I getting wrong? How can I get the list of all the companies in the drop-down?

Thanks!

Comment: is it in  `<iframe>` ? It would need `driver.switch_to.frame(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This element is inside `<iframe>` and Selenium treads frame like separated content/page and you have to use `browser.switch_to.frame(...)` to access it.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
#browser = webdriver.Firefox()

url = ('https://www.goodjobsfirst.org/violation-tracker')
browser.get(url)
browser.maximize_window()

frame = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
print('frame:', frame)

browser.switch_to.frame(frame)

element = browser.find_element_by_id("edit-field-violation-parent-value")
print('element:', element)

select = Select(select)
print('options number:', len(select.options))

for number, item in enumerate(select.options, 1):
    print(number, item.text)

# go back to main content
#browser.switch_to.default_content()

browser.quit()
```

Comment: thanks! how do I know whether the element is an iframe?

Comment: normally check if there is tag `<iframe>` in HTML saved on disk, or using `DevTools` in Firefox/Chrome, or using `find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")` in Selenium. And then you can try to use `switch_to.frame()`